# How to write to file elements of arrays in a particular pattern

Tags: fortran

I want to write to file elements of the three arrays: k= (/1, 2 /), kp = (/1, 2 /), w(k,kp) = (/1,2 ,3,4/)

in the following pattern, using Fortran:

```
k    kp    w(k,kp)

1    1    1
1    2    2
2    1    3
2    2    4
```

I know how to write for column "kp" and "w", but how can I write  column "k" ?

I have my  code as:

```
  write(20,*) "k" , "kp", "W"
  do i = 1,2
            do j = 1, 2
             write (20,*) k( )   kp(j)  , W(i,j)
            end do
  end do
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework problem?

```
 program foo
 implicit none
 integer :: i, j, k(2)  = [1,2], kp(2) = [1,2]
 integer :: w(2,2)  = reshape([1,3,2,4], [2,2])
  do j = 1, 2
    do i = 1, 2
       write(*,'(*(1X,I0))') k(j), kp(i), w(k(j),kp(i))
    end do
  end do
end program foo
```

Comment: Thank you, it's part of research. Actually, it's for a larger data set. I just used those arrays as example.